# Capitalize the first letter of sentense in JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, string

## this is a test. this is one more test. and this also new test.

This is test. This is one more test. And this is new test.

Comment: @Satpal This is not the exact duplicate, however that can help to solve this problem

Comment: Like @Tushar says. The link don't answer the question. And according to the tags I would like an answer in vanilla Js. This question is a bit poorly formatted thou.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can use Javascript `string` and `array` functions.

1. Split the string by `.`, to separate different sentences
2. Trim each sentence
3. Capitalize first letter
4. Join by `.`

```js
var str = 'this is a test. this is one more test. and this also new test.';

var newStr = str.split('.').map(function(el) {
  el = el.trim();
  return el.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + el.substr(1);
}).join('. ');

alert(newStr.trim());
```